# syntax error in defintion. expecting something else

Tags: ruby

I think my mind is not able to figure this out:

```
def parameters(rjust_options, sym1, sym2)
    sym1 = rjust_options[sym1] || 5
    sym2 = rjust_options[sym2] || "0"
    sym1, sym2
end
```

error

```
syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting '='
```

so i just want the returned values. what am i missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not valid syntax for Ruby `var1, var2` (only with several assigment like `sym1, sym2 = 1, 2`) try this:

```
def parameters(rjust_options, sym1, sym2)
  sym1 = rjust_options[sym1] || 5
  sym2 = rjust_options[sym2] || "0"
  [sym1, sym2]
end
```

This should return array with two variables `sym1` and `sym2`.

As @JamalAbdulNasir say in comment you can use `return sym1, sym2` too.

But i  prefer more readable array brackets.

Comment: Ok. so :a,:b = [1,2] and :a = 1 doesn't work. 
a,b = [1,2] does.
Is there a way to assign to symbols and splat to multiple symbols?

Comment: you can't make assignment to symbol (`:a`) in ruby `:a,:b = [1,2]` this invalid but this `a,b = [1,2]` valid.

Comment: the brackets are optional in the return statement. if you don't want to put brackets then use `return sym1, sym2`.

Comment: @JamalAbdulNasir yep, `return sym1, sym2` return array `[sym1, sym2]` too, i prefer more readable with array brackets.